# ruby: how to combine if and unless

Tags: ruby

I have following sample code using if and unless

```
if key.start_with('abc')
   do something
end

unless key.start_with('abc')
   do that
end
```

is this the correct way to combine both if and unless or is there any other way?

```
if key.start_with('abc')
   do something
elsif !key.start_with('abc')
   do that
else
   do this
end
```

Thanks

Comment: In the code you've shown, the third branch ("do this") will never be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be conflating terms here.  In Ruby, `unless` is equivalent to `if !condition`.

If you want to ensure that something either does or doesn't happen based on a single condition, all you need to check is *that* condition.  In your example, it would be:

```
if key.start_with('abc')
 do something
else
  do that
end
```

Either `key.startWith('abc')` is true or false.  There's no reason to check the additional false statement, since it *must* be false after execution.

Comment: Thanks and sorry just updated question. what if i have another else statement?

Comment: My answer clearly illustrates that.  You can't have three conditions on one boolean variable.

Answer (score 1):

If the check `if key.start_with('abc')` fails, then that means that it does not start with `abc`, so there's no need to check for that condition. They are direct opposites, so if one is true, the other is false, therefore, a plain `if`/`else` is sufficient:

```
if key.start_with('abc')
   do something
else
   do that
end
```

As I stated in my comment, how you set up your `if`/`elsif`/`else` is dependent on how your conditions are related to one another. If they are all mutually exclusive, then it can simply be something like:

```
if condition1
   do first thing
elsif condition2
   do 2nd thing
else
   do fallback thing
end
```

However, there are many different ways you might want to check:

```
if condition1
   do a thing
elsif condition2 || condition3
   do something if 1 is false, but either either 2 or 3 are true
elsif condition4
   do something if 1,2, & 3 are all false
elsif condition5 && condition6
   do something only if both 5 and 6 are true (and all above are false)
```

etc, etc

Comment: Thanks. what if i have another else statement? updated question

Comment: It depends on how all of those statements are related. Your initial question was a simple mutually exclusive relationship, but we would need to know more about the additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the ruby style guide:
https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-else-with-unless

I would stay away from `unless` for most control flow cases as it quickly becomes confusing, except for the following:

- a one liner:

`do that unless key.start_with('abc')`

- or a guard clause:

`return unless key.start_with('abc')`